# How to implement 'And' function in perceptron in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron

I am a newbie to machine learning and scikit-learn. I was trying to implement 'and' function in scikit-learn and written a small code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = DataFrame([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,1]],columns=list('abc'))
X = df[['a','b']]
y=df['c']

scalar_model = StandardScaler()

train_test_split =X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

scalar_model = StandardScaler()

scalar_model.fit(X_train)

X_train_std = scalar_model.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = scalar_model.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron

#perceptron initialization
ppn = Perceptron(n_iter = 100,eta0=0.1,random_state=0)

#fit the model with standardized data
ppn.fit(X_train_std,y_train)

#make predications
y_pred = ppn.predict(X_test_std)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100
error = (1-accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))*100


print("Accuracy: {} %".format(accuracy))
print("error: {} %".format(error))
```

After running the code I am getting the following results:

```
  Accuracy: 0.0 %
    error: 100.0 %
```

Here are my questions :

1. why is the perceptron not training after 100 iterations.
2. I have read from the manual that if weights are not assigned to the features they are automatically assigned.
3. If i want to assign the weights to the features randomly in the range of 0 and 1 How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By splitting your already tiny data set - you don't give Perceptron a chance to learn properly. Beside that in this case it doesn't make any sense to scale input data set.

Demo:

```
In [257]: ppn.fit(X,y)
Out[257]:
Perceptron(alpha=0.0001, class_weight=None, eta0=0.1, fit_intercept=True,
      max_iter=None, n_iter=100, n_jobs=1, penalty=None, random_state=0,
      shuffle=True, tol=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

In [258]: ppn.predict([[1,1], [0,1]])
Out[258]: array([1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thank you. If my training data has 10 feature columns in the form of ['D-0','D-1','D-2','D-3','D-4','D-5','D-6','D-7','D-8','D-9'] and one output label 'C'.
How can I assign weights to the features randomly in between 0 and 1 .